# How can I find solutions to a matrix if the elements in the solution vector is a $0 \pmod 2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-factorization, gaussian-elimination, programming

## Quadratic Sieve

---

I am attempting to program the Quadratic Sieve algorithm for factoring large composite numbers. I have selected my composite number to be factored, $n$:
\begin{align}
n = 87463
\end{align}

---

I have completed the sieving phase and am now onto the linear algebra phase. Per my instructions, I have created a matrix, $M$, comprised of exponents and reduced its elements by $\pmod 2$.

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}

I have converted M to reduced echelon form. I am searching for an algorithm to generate solution vectors, *λ*, such that *λ* ⋅ *M* = 0 (mod 2).

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

I know that the solution vector, $\lambda$, is comprised of $0$'s and $1$'s, where there must be at least two $1$'s (or else the vector won't be useful in factorization process). The follow vector is a valid solution, but isn't useful in factoring $n$.

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

---

I am sorry if any of this is misconstrued/incorrect, I am still very confused myself. I can provide any extra details if needed, thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Here is the console output from my latest attempt. If you can spot any errors in my process, please let me know because right now the generated $x$ & $y$ values are incorrect.

```
Number to be factored, n=87463.
Size of the factor base, B=14.
The primes in the factor base: [-1, 2, 3, 13, 17, 19, 29].
The number of primes in the factor base, K=6.
[1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Sieve Results (x-value, x^2-n, vector of exponents):
296 153 [0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0]
299 1938 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
307 6786 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
278 -10179 [1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1]
316 12393 [0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0]
265 -17238 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0]

M = 6 X 7
Created from the sieving process (rows are exponents from above)

0 0 2 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 2 1 0 0 1
1 0 3 1 0 0 1
0 0 6 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 2 1 0 0

M modulo 2

0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 0 0

Transposed M

0 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0

Reduced Row Echelon Form

1 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Solution vector: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
x = 83740
y = 14616
gcd(x-y, n) = 1
```

---

Here are the formulas I'm using to generate $x$ & $y$:
$$x = \prod_{i=1}^{K+2} x_i^{\lambda_i} \pmod n$$
$$y = \prod_{i=1}^{K+2} (x_i^2-n)^{\lambda_i/2} \pmod n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lambda \cdot M = 0 \pmod{2}$, it means

$\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_5=0$ and there are no restriction on the other entries.

$$\lambda = (0,a,b,c,0,d)$$

You have the freedom to choose $a,b,c,d\in \{ 0,1\}$ and they are valid solution to the system $\lambda \cdot M  =0 \pmod{2}.$

Edit:

It seems initially you want to solve $\lambda \cdot M = 0$,

after which a transpose is taken:
$$M^T \cdot \lambda^T = 0$$

and we reduce $M^T$ to reduce row echelon form, call it $R$.

$$R \cdot \lambda^T = 0$$

where

For $$R = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

The first $4$ variables are pivot variable and the remaining $2$ are not.

We get to select $\lambda_5$ and $\lambda_6$ and we have

$$\lambda_1 = \lambda_5 + \lambda_6.$$
$$\lambda_2 = 0$$
$$\lambda_3 = \lambda_6$$
$$\lambda_4 = \lambda_6$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am running into a new problem now, if you could please check my edit above that would be great.

Comment: Not sure if it is a mistake, should $19$ and $29$ be in the factor base?

Comment: So in my instructions, it's recommended that the primes in the factor base are all smaller than B. That didn't work so I added an extra prime (that's why 17 is in there). Should I be adding 3 extra primes instead of just 1 extra? How do I determine the size of the factor base?

Comment: Either way, I changed the implementation to have a larger factor base and the results were still incorrect. I updated the output above. Thanks for your help so far, I really appreciate it.

Comment: not sure, dunno much about number theory. just a doubt though, $M$ is $8$ by $7$, but $\lambda$ is $1$ by $7$?

Comment: are we suppose to solve for $M. \lambda = 0$ instead?

Comment: Edited my answer in case you really want to solve $M\cdot \lambda = 0$.

Comment: I just edited my post. Now I think my problem is with generating solution vectors. I wrote an algorithm based on your original post, but I guess I am confused as to how you knew which entries had to be zero. As you can see, the generated solution does not actually work.

Comment: Are you solving $M \cdot \lambda = 0$ or $\lambda \cdot M = 0$?

Comment: To be more clear, I want to create a solution for the now transposed matrix. I think that means I am looking to solve it as you first presumed. I think I do want to solve λ ⋅ M = 0.

Comment: Can you see if the latest edit work?

Comment: Nice, now my algorithm generates valid solution vectors! I have updated the solution vector above, but the values for x and y are still incorrect. If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks again for all of your help thus far.

Comment: [My python code](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_PlUkCAaHOUkU9UC.py) I experimented with the algorithm, and found the factors to be $587$ and $149$. I don't think any solution to the linear system works. Only  some solution works.

Comment: Thank you! I have it working now. The only thing that would make it better is if I had an algorithm for generating all of the possible solution vectors. Right now I just generate a random solution, if it doesn't factorize n, I generate another. For really large integers this process makes my implementation really slow. Do you know if there is a simple way to generate all the possible combinations for a solutions vector (note: I have an array of which columns can be either 0 or 1)?

Comment: Solving a linear system and solving a binary linear system is the same idea. Express pivot variables as a function of free variable. read up on how to solve for example [here](https://www.math.uh.edu/~jiwenhe/math2331/lectures/sec1_2.pdf)

Comment: Ok thank you again, you've been most helpful.